# Warnings in gcc compiler

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm gonna make a program that convolves a matrix, but first I need to create this matrix and load it with random numbers, but in my methods to do this I received warnings and I cannot resolve this because I am newbie in this and this is gonna make me crazy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 5
#define COL 5

// Create a Matrix
int **generateMatrix(int row, int col){
  int **mat;
  mat=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);
  for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
    mat[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
  }
  if(mat==NULL){
    printf("Insufficient Memory...");
    return 0;
  }
  return mat;
}

// Load a Matrix
int loadMatrix(int *x[][COL], int row, int col){
  int i;
  for(int r=0;r<row;r++){
      for(int c=0;c<col;c++){
        x[r][c]=rand()%256;
    }
  }
  return x;
}

// Print a Matrix
void printMatrix(int *x[][COL], int row, int col){
  for(int r=0;r<row;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<col;c++){
      printf("\t%d", x[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(){
  int **matrix, **kernel;

  // Create the Matrix
  matriz=generateMatrix(ROW, COL);
  kernel=generateMatrix(3,3);

  // Load the Matrix
  loadMatrix(matrix, ROW, COL);
  loadMatrix(kernel, 3, 3);

  // Print Matrix
  printf("Matrix\n");
  printMatrix(matrix, ROW, COL);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Kernel\n");
  printMatrix(kernel, 3, 3);
  printf("\n");

  free(matrix);
  free(kernel);
}
```

The warnings I received are bellow

```
main.c:25:20: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]                                  
main.c:28:14: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]                                      
main.c:35:22: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]                  
main.c:49:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘loadMatrix’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]         
main.c:21:9: note: expected ‘int * (*)[5]’ but argument is of type ‘int **’                                                     
main.c:50:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘loadMatrix’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]         
main.c:21:9: note: expected ‘int * (*)[5]’ but argument is of type ‘int **’                                                     
main.c:54:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printMatrix’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]        
main.c:32:10: note: expected ‘int * (*)[5]’ but argument is of type ‘int **’                                                    
main.c:58:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printMatrix’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]        
main.c:32:10: note: expected ‘int * (*)[5]’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
```

Comment: `int *x[][COL]` should be `int **x` (both places). The parameter should match the type of what you are passing to it (which is `int **`)

Comment: Your check for `if (mat == NULL)` is far too late (it should be before the loop, not after it), and you don't check for failure to allocate each row, either.

Comment: Note that you should not edit the question so that the error messages are no longer accurate — you don't update the question to include the answer (unless you also keep the original code and explain why the revised code is correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you must think a bit on how do you want to build the matrix thing.

Let's say we are talking about a 5x5 array of int

- Plan A: `int kernel[][]`

We will have a starting address `kernel` and 5 x 5 x `sizeof(int)` values, let's say 4 bytes to a total of 100 bytes using a 32-bits compiler. This way you would declare as `int kernel[5][5]`. And `kernel[0]` is `int[5]`

- Plan B: `int** kernel`

We will have `kernel` as a pointer to an array of pointers to `int`, starting at `*kernel`. It is another animal. `kernel` points to an area that has pointers to `int`. Let's say we have also 5 of them. `kernel` then points to an area of 5 pointers to `int`. Not an array of `int`. Just 5 `int`. In order to each one point to an array of 5 `int` we should have declared `kernel` as `int* kernel[5];` and in this case `*kernel[0]` up to `*kernel[4]` would indeed point to an array of 5 `int`.

But note that we have no way of knowing how many pointers are in `*kernel`.
This is the reason why `main()` is declared `int main(int argc, char** argv);`: someone must tell the program how many pointers are in `*argv`.

Back to your code:

You must use this knowledge in `generateMatriz()` and `loadMatriz()`.

To use array notation the last dimension must be constant. But see your prototype for `loadMatriz()`

```
int loadMatriz(int* x[][COL], int row, int col);
```

what is `x` here? It is not Plan A. It is not plan B. `x` is and array of pointers to `int`. Each element of `x` is a pointer to `int`. And it is not what you passed on `main()`:

```
int main() {
    int** matriz, ** kernel;

    // Create the Matriz
    matriz = generateMatriz(ROW, COL);
    kernel = generateMatriz(3, 3);

    // Load the Matriz
    loadMatriz(matriz, ROW, COL);
    loadMatriz(kernel, 3, 3);
```

`kernel` is `int**`. It is not `int*[][]`. Think about this. This is the reason of the compiler errors: you must build the matrix according to plan ;)

Comment: Good to know! Time to plan :)